# iOS interface orientation

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, interface, orientation

How can I enable rotation of the Interface without override UIViewController method:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAuorotateToInterfaceOrientation
```

I don't have UIViewController class in my app, just only UIView.

Comment: If you don't have a controller, how do you manage all the actions?

Comment: You will have to create a view controller. It's fun and does not hurt one little bit...

Comment: its very big change in the code, and i need only this metod...

Comment: Why would it be a very big change? Your current view should be the new view controllers view - simple as that.

Comment: Not using controllers is a terrible practice in iOS development. The entire architecture is built considering MVC, you should not stray from that. Placing code in the view is bad practice.

Comment: And I mean actions as in your functions and such, those go in the controller, simple as that.

Comment: Is it even possible to have only UIView? The App Delegate will cry for a rootViewController wouldn't it? or are you just strapping all your UIViews straight to the window?

Comment: He is most likely doing as you state Ryan, he probably has a generic UIViewController and is just modifying the window. And he's probably just ignoring the UIViewController created by default in his app and throwing the code in the view file.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a controller you'll have to create one first for this to work.
At the settings *.plist file you have two options called "Supported interface orientations" and "Supported interface orientations (iPad)". Enable the ones you want to support.

Then at the UIViewControllers you want to support orientations, you'll have to override `-(BOOL)shouldAuorotateToInterfaceOrientation` to return `YES` at the orientations you want to support and write all the necessary drawing code to position everything in their proper places.